# IntelliJ dependency package not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use scala-chart (https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) to create some simple charts in Scala.

Following the code [here](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) I have made the following:

```
import scalax._

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val data    = Seq((1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,8))
    val dataset = data.toXYSeriesCollection("some points")

  }
}
```

I have added scalax as another module and and added that as a dependency as so: [image: Dependencies]

However I have several issue with this. First off just using the editor it seems to recognise the library have been added just fine and if i do scalax.chart.. it autocompletes things for me and see all the classes in the library.

However on data.toXYSeriesCollection it the editor says: "Cannot resolve symbol: toXYSeriesCollection".

The second issue is when I compile it, I get an error already on the import statement:

[image: Compiler errors]

Anyone know what is going on here? Your help is much appreciate.

Comment: why not to use SBT and sbt-idea plugin, which will do all the work for you?

Comment: that is a lot of setup to just use one extra library.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Alexiv. You should really just use sbt and the sbt-idea plugin. You say "that is a lot of setup", but even for your one project you would have been already faster with this approach than figuring out why the library is not on the classpath of your project in the manual configuration.

And for your second project, that cost is already amortised. For simplicity, I will show how this works with the sbt launcher script installed in your project directory. Generally, you should follow [the approach here](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) and use `~/bin`, implying that you set up your bash `PATH` appropriately.

```
$ mkdir ~/test_project
$ cd ~/test_project
$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > sbt && chmod 0755 sbt
...
$ mkdir -p ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins
$ echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")' > ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt
$ ./sbt -sbt-create
...
> set scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
...
> set libraryDependencies += "com.github.wookietreiber" %% "scala-chart" % "0.3.0"
...
> session save
> gen-idea
...
> exit
$ mkdir -p src/main/scala/mypackage
$ open -a "IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE" .
```

Comment: Then for your example to work, you need `import scalax.chart.Charting._`, this contains the enrichment methods like `.toXYSeriesCollection`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Maven.

In IntelliJ i went into file->Project Structure->Libraries-> click the plus icon->add via Maven.

This was much easier than having to install homebrew, sbt, then the i the IntelliJ plugins. This was builtin and required no further installation.

Comment: From your screenshot, you seem to be using OS X. You don't need homebrew to install anything of this. The fastest for sbt is really just to curl the paulp script, it will take care of installing sbt itself.

Comment: I had a look at the guidelines here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#installing-sbt which does say you should install sbt via homebrew. As far as I can see all the IntelliJ plugins requires you to have sbt installed beforehand. But maybe I misunderstood it. None the less I believe my answer is still easier than using the sbt method you outlined in your answer.